# Invalid use of undefined type 'struct PelephonePH'

Tags: c++

i have received in .cpp errors of invalid use of undefined struct PelephonePN, CellcomPN and so on
and also error in .h errors of forward declaration of PelephonePN,...

```
#ifndef PHONE_H_INCLUDED
#define PHONE_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include "phone.h"

using namespace std;

class PhoneNumber;
class PelephonePN;
class CellcomPN;
class OrangePN;
class HotPN;
class BezeqPN;

class PhoneManager
{
private:
    PelephonePN* mpPelephone;
    CellcomPN* mpCellcom;
    OrangePN* mpOrange;
    HotPN* mpHot;
    BezeqPN* mpBezeq;
public:
    PhoneManager();
    ~PhoneManager();
    void split_check_data(string str);
};

#endif
```

and .cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "phone_manager.h"
#include "phone.h"


using namespace std;

PhoneManager::PhoneManager()
{
    srand(time(0));
    mpPelephone = new PelephonePN();
    mpCellcom = new CellcomPN();
    mpOrange = new OrangePN();
    mpHot = new HotPN();
    mpBezeq = new BezeqPN();
    mpPelephone->add(mpCellcom);
    mpPelephone->add(mpOrange);
    mpPelephone->add(mpHot);
    mpPelephone->add(mpBezeq);
    mpBezeq->setNext(mpPelephone);
}
```

Comment: Try formatting your question so it is readable. And *never, never, never* use `using namespace std` in a header file. Never.

Comment: I formatted your question for you. The first reformatting is free ;-) Next time, please use the `{}` button.

Comment: You don't define them (Or at least you hide that piece of code from me). That's it.

Comment: Why are you even `using namespace std` in the header? Not only is this bad practice, it's not even required in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

To instantiate an object, forward declaration is just insufficient. Include the corresponding headers in the source file. In the body of the constructor, you are instantiating `mpPelephone, ....`. So, make sure that corresponding class headers can be seen in the translation unit.

Comment: But not in the header files. Using `#include "kitchen_sink.h"` in a header can make the build process take forever because one simple change means everything needs to be recompiled.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.cpp` source file you need to `#include` the headers that define `class PelephonePN` and its associates.

It is fine to *forward-declare* these `class`es in the header if you are only using them as pointers or references, but one you start *using* them in your implementation, you'll need to provide the compiler with the *definition*.

Comment: class PelephonePN defined in phone.h that i have included

Comment: @user782642: Definitely *defined* and not *declared*? Are you sure your compiler is picking up the correct "phone.h"? (`gcc -E` is a great tool for checking this)

Comment: @user782642: Then why do you need forward declarations? Anyway, you better post `phone.h`.

Comment: @boaz-yaniv: Forward declarations should be preferred in header files as they reduce the compile-time dependencies.

Comment: But again, why would you need them if they are already present? Either have them to reduce dependencies or remove to header where they are defined (`phone.h` in this case). Having both when its unnecessary is bad practice.

Comment: @Boaz Yaniv: Ah, sorry. I see what you're saying! Indeed; there is no need to `#include "phone.h"` in the header file here. I remain to be convinced that `class PelephonePN` is **defined** in "phone.h".

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a forward declaration of a class to access its members (which includes the constructor, default or otherwise) or its size and without those two things, you can't instantiate an instance of that class.

You require its FULL implementation to do that, so in your `.cpp` file you need to include the header with the whole `class PelephonePN {/* class body */};` section.

Comment: but i did it phone.h it 's a header where i have my class PelephonePN

Comment: @user782642: maybe you should post the contents of `phone.h`, cause there could be an error in its definition.

Answer (score 0):

in the first file you have lines:

```
#ifndef PHONE_H_INCLUDED
#define PHONE_H_INCLUDED
```

I suppose you have same lines in phone.h, please check...

Comment: Ah nice catch, I didn't see that!

Answer (score 0):

Are your PelephonePN and co. in a particular namespace? If so, predeclarations must all be in the same namespace. Since you added a using namespace std (sigh), my guess is that phone.h is defining your classes inside the namespace std (I hope it doesn't, but that's another thing).
If so, your predeclarations must be:
    namespace std {
        class PelephonePN;
    }

Btw, what is a pelephone??? O.O

Comment: Pelephone is one of the three major mobile phone carriers in Israel. Cellcom and Orange are the other two.